# Inline entity form field alter

Tags: 8, forms, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce. For the Variations, I am using multiple add /remove via AJAX.

I need to make field readonly.

```
0 -> <input type="number" name="variations[form][inline_entity_form][entities][0][form][field_stock][0][value]" value="0" step="1" placeholder="" class="form-number" />

1 -> <input type="number" name="variations[form][inline_entity_form][entities][1][form][field_stock][0][value]" value="0" step="1" placeholder="" class="form-number" />
```

I have given example with 2 variations. How can I achieve it via `form_alter` ?

On Add of variation I need to unset that field and at the edit time need to make readonly.

Already checked with `hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()` but it is not going there.

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form/issues/2452051#comment-10195121 i think you should add `#after_build` in your `hook_form_alter` and add your logic in the after_build callback

Comment: Thanks @berramou. Yes it's going in to `#after_build`. But I am still not able to get that field which needed.

Comment: if  #afterbuild does not work do it with Javascript  eg attach a library with in the cart then $('input[name^="variations[form][inline_entity_form][entities]"]' ) ... do the stuff

Comment: Hi @TaggartJensen Yes right now able to manage via JS. It would be great it able to manage via Drupal level from alter.